# Makefile executable not generated

Tags: makefile, g++

```
CC=g++ 
CFLAGS=-c -o 
PROG=craps 
LIBSRCS=craps.cpp craps_game.cpp craps_helper.cpp craps_io.cpp
LIBOBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(LIBSRCS)) 
LIBCRAPS=craps 
CXXFLAGS=-I./ -fpic 
LDFLAGS=-L./ 

all: $(PROG) 

$(PROG): $(LIBSRCS) 
       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o 

$(LIBCRAPS): $(LIBOBJS) 
       $(CC) -shared -o lib$(LIBCRAPS).so $(LIBOBJS) 

%.o: %.cpp 
     $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $ 

depend:
    ${CC} -MM ${PROG}.cpp ${LIBSCRS} > depends.mak

include depends.mak
```

Why executable file not compiled and generated?

All o files generated with no error.

Why this line `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o` does not run ? what is wrong ?

Comment: Is your actual makefile missing the newline after `PROG=craps` like you have in your example here?

Comment: When asking questions like this it's best to show exactly what command you typed and exactly what output you got.  Just saying "does not run" is not sufficiently specific for someone to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist no it is not missing it is shown on question, the 3rd line, `(PROG=craps)` just I forgot to add line, just check

Comment: @MadScientist no error show nothing, all o file generated correctly axcept this line not executed `$(PROG):   
     $(LIBSRCS) $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o `

Comment: @MadScientist I have understand your comment well, and I said my mistake not formating the question, I forgot to add new line, means to separate them each in one line

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood my comment.  I'm saying this this:

```
PROG=craps LIBSRCS=craps.cpp craps_game.cpp craps_helper.cpp craps_io.cpp
```

is wrong.  You can't assign two variables on the same line, in a makefile.  These variables must look like this:

```
PROG=craps
LIBSRCS=craps.cpp craps_game.cpp craps_helper.cpp craps_io.cpp
```

I'm asking, is the latter how your actual makefile looks, or is the example you provided here just inaccurate.

Also these rules both have incorrect newlines:

```
 $(PROG): 
           $(LIBSRCS) $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o 

 $(LIBCRAPS):  
           $(LIBOBJS) $(CC) -shared -o lib$(LIBCRAPS).so $(LIBOBJS)
```

You are adding the prerequisite lists `$(LIBSRCS)` and `$(LIBOBJS)` into the recipe (shell commands) used to build the target.  Prerequisites must be on the same line as the target.  These should look like this:

```
 $(PROG): $(LIBSRCS)
           $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o 

 $(LIBCRAPS): $(LIBOBJS)
           $(CC) -shared -o lib$(LIBCRAPS).so $(LIBOBJS)
```

**This is your problem, below**

Finally, you can't have both the program and the target have the same name:

```
PROG=craps
LIBCRAPS=craps
```

You can only create one target with a given name so the value of both these variables cannot be `craps`.  Maybe you wanted:

```
PROG = craps
LIBCRAPS = libcraps.so
```

Assuming the makefile you've quoted here is identical to what you're running, you must be getting warnings like this from `make` when you run this makefile:

```
 Makefile:15: warning: overriding recipe for target 'craps'
 Makefile:12: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'craps'
```

These warnings are why you are not seeing the compile rule invoked: the library rule is overriding it just as the warning says.

Also, you should have the program depend on the library (since it links it) and the object file `$(PROG).o` because currently make doesn't know it needs to be built.  And you don't need to have it depend on all the source files.  You want something like:

```
$(PROG): $(LIBCRAPS) $(PROG).o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o
```

Comment: you are correct, that is what I did in makefile, I did not notice that once I have post the question, The only issue I have is why this line is not executed, all makefiles line executed except this one: 
`$(PROG): $(LIBSRCS) 
            $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o `

Comment: I have format the question as exactly my makefile, all o files are generated with no issues, no errors shown, but this line not executed: `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(PROG) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o 
`  why?